# Error when reading Outlook calendar from Rails application when started as a mongrel_service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook

I have recently implemented something in a rails application that allows me to read appointments of the Outlook calendar. This works sufficiently well. But when I tried to use it in production mode by starting it through `mongrel_service`, the whole thing stopped working and gave me the following error message:

```
failed to create WIN32OLE object from `Outlook.Application'
HRESULT error code:0x80080005
  Starten des Servers fehlgeschlagen (german for: start of server failed)
```

So the problem seems to be the wrong account for the `mongrel_service`. Is it possible to configure it correctly?

Comment: Is it run on a different machine in production mode?

Comment: No, it is run on the same machine. It is in production mode installed as a service in windows, by using mongrel_service. I have played around a little bit, and I think the real reason is, that the service does not not which outlook profile to use. I tried to configure the service that it runs with the same account, but could not get it right. When I start the rails application from the command line (with -e production), it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading up on some forum posts, it seems that running your application in service mode will not be easy - or even feasible (for example have a look at: [outlook and win32 service](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/148917)).

That being said, perhaps there are other ways to read calendar items from an Exchange server (assuming you are using Exchange), like for example using IMAP ([Exchange calendar to Ruby object](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/243961)).

Comment: I have done one more test, and it seems that you are right. My next try will be to extract the function in a little script that I may start at will, that is not part of the rails application, but changes the data there. Not the best solution, but should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have written the following script:

> ruby script\runner 'AppointmentController.new.refresh_no_redirect'

I start this script regularly instead of using the button inside the Rails application. Because I start it by hand, my credentials are used and it works pretty well. So no solution for the original question, but one workaround that works well for me.